# How to place sprite in center of another bigger sprite?

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have a PNG that is 80x80.

I have another png that will fit inside of the 80x80 png. I dont know what the exact width and height of the second png will be but it will be smaller than 80x80.

I have a method that i use `png.setPosition(x,y)` to set the png position. I also have a method called `getX()` and `getY()` that will allow us to retrieve the second png's dimensions.

What i would like to do is get the x and y that would place the second png in the center of the 80x80 png.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, find the middle of your big sprite.

```
midX = img1.getPositionX()+img1.getWidth()/2;
midY = img1.getPositionY()+img1.getHeight()/2;
```

Then, to that mid position, remove the half of the dimensions of the second image:

```
midX-=img2.getWidth()/2;
midY-=img2.getHeight()/2;
```

And set that position to your smaller than 80x80 png

```
img2.setPosition(midX,midY);
```

Comment: drawing staff on a piece of paper(or directly in your mind), can help you on these situations!

Answer (score 1):

I created a card game and I used this method to set a card in a deck:

```
card.setPositionX(deck.getPositionX() + ((deck.getWidth() - card.getWidth()) / 2));
card.setPositionY(deck.getPositionY() + ((deck.getHeight() - card.getHeight()) / 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the second image to the first (If you are using AndEngine's AnchorCenter branch, coordinate systems start in the bottom-left corner of an entity)

Image2 position will be in reference to image1. So you can do:

```
image1.attachChild(image2);
image2.setPosition(image1.getWidth()/2, image1.getHeight()/2);
```

With this solution you can move image1 and image2 will continue in the middle of image1